# Optimizing file locking for 1000+ concurrent NFS users: What is the best practice?

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency, locking, nfs

I'm developing a Bash script for a project involving NFS (specifically NFS3 and NFS4), aimed at managing critical sections. The script must efficiently handle over a thousand concurrent processes across various computers. Currently, I'm using Bash's `noclobber` option for file locking, but I'm uncertain about its suitability and effectiveness in this high-concurrency, distributed setting.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

lockfile="/mnt/nfs_dir/mylockfile.lock"

# Function to clean up lockfile
cleanup() {
    rm -f "$lockfile"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

# Attempt to acquire lock
if ( set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then
    trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT
    
    # Critical section starts
    # ...
    # Critical section ends

    rm -f "$lockfile"
    trap - INT TERM EXIT
else
    echo "Failed to acquire lock."
fi
```

**Questions & Concerns:**

- Scalability and Reliability: Can the `noclobber` approach effectively scale in a high-concurrency environment, especially with NFS and over a thousand workers from different computers?
- Alternative methods: Would `flock` or other file locking mechanisms be more appropriate in this scenario? What about [DLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager) solutions?

Comment: I believe `mkdir` on an NFS filesystem is atomic, so can be used for advisory locking: `if mkdir /lock/dir; then : critical_section; rmdir /lock/dir; else echo failed; fi` . but do you really want everything to fail instead of queueing?